# How to avoid System.out getting closed from Callback

Tags: java, callback, jaxb, system.out

I want to output the generated schema to the stdout. So I set the System.out as the outputStream of SchemaOutputResolver. `StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);`

But after the statement: 
`jc.generateSchema(outputResolver)`

System.out.println() doesn't work anymore. By debugging the code I got that System.out was closed after `jc.generateSchema` Method.

```
  JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeObject.class);
  SchemaOutputResolver outputResolver = new SchemaOutputResolver() {

    @Override
    public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName)
        throws IOException {

      StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

      result.setSystemId(namespaceUri);


      // return result
      return result;
    }
  };
  jc.generateSchema(outputResolver);
  System.out.println("this String can't be output");
```

My Question is, how to output the generated schema to stdout without closing the System.out by using `jc.generateSchema`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `PrintStream` class (say, `UncloseablePrintStream`) that just wraps another `PrintStream` and ignores the `close` call, then do:

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new UncloseablePrintStream(System.out)));
```

**Completely** untested, but it may be this simple:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class UncloseablePrintStream extends PrintStream {
    public UncloseablePrintStream(PrintStream ps) {
        super(ps);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  That's just what I want. I wrote some similar class but hat no idea how to assign the System.out to the wrap class. :) Thank you for your nice Code.

Answer (score 2):

You could print to a ByteArrayOutputStream and then use that as you'd like:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(ps);
System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

result.setSystemId(namespaceUri);
```